# Is it possible to increase the decimal values of latitude and longitude value to get the location of nearest place?

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding

In my application, using latitude and longitude i need to find the location. some times it shows as couldn't find the location. In some locations, i'm getting correct location. so if i increase the decimal values of the latitude and longitude, then will i atleast get the nearest location? if so how can i increase the decimal value from last?

Answer (score 0):

Use loc.getAccuracy() method to check the accuracy level of location you received. If the value is less then 10(or less than that) then you can consider it , otherwise wait for location Lister to fetch another location.

getLastKnownLocation is your last known location, dont use just getAccuracy also check the time.

Better dont use getLastKnownLocation if you need only accurate location.

To increase the accuracy:

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);  
lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

ACCURACY_HIGH less than 100 meters 
ACCURACY_MEDIUM between 100 - 500 meters 
ACCURACY_LOW greater than 500 meters

Comment: i understand. but my question is, can i increase the decimal value to get a location address when it shows as cant get the location!

Comment: are you using criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);  
?

Comment: no i'll get lat and long value and use geocoder class to get the address

Comment: now what should i do? lm will have the best provider?